# CNN - convolution down the center line of the image

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I was wondering whether is it possible to instruct CNNs (e.g. ideally in Keras, but if not in other package) to **only** run the convolution down the center of the image? Please see image below - the blue and the orange box would be different size filters that run down in stepwise fashion with their midpoint on the centre-line of the image from left to right. Many thanks in advance! 
[image]